# Prototype JS: Can't get Element.update to work on element with a class

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am trying to add the ajax response text, to a div that has a class on it, and not an id. I try the following:

```
var notice = $$('.testdiv');
Element.update(notice, transport.responseText)
```

This doesn't work but if I change it to update an element that has an ID on it, it works.

```
var notice = $('testdiv');
Element.update(notice, transport.responseText)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `$$('.testdiv')` is returning an array. Try this:

```
Element.update(notice[0], transport.responseText)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I am use to jQuery and didn't realize that. It makes sense